# How validate digit in javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, integer, numbers

I'm working on a JavaScript project where I need to validate if a user-provided input is an integer and disallow float values. I want to implement a check where only whole numbers are accepted and both decimal and float values are rejected.

Consider the following examples:

```
var input1 = 10.4; // Should not be allowed
var input2 = 10.0; // Should not be allowed
var input3 = 10;   // Should be allowed
```

I want to create a validation function in JavaScript that can distinguish between these cases. If the input is an integer, it should be deemed valid; otherwise, it should be considered invalid.
I've started with the following code:

```
function validateInteger(input) {
    // Need code here to check if input is an integer
}

validateInteger(input1);
validateInteger(input2);
validateInteger(input3);
```

How can I modify the validateInteger function to effectively validate whether the provided input is an integer and not a float? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please note `10.0` and `10` are the same when expressed as numbers

Comment: I've tried using Numbers method but they allow zero after decimal (10.0),so it doesn't work for me...that's why need a better solution,any help would be appreciated

Comment: `<input type="number" step="1"`?

Comment: @sayantan_06 how do you get that user input?

Comment: @GrafiCode yup,i know but that's why i'm confused!Actually i need only iteger value...nothing other than that!

Comment: @VLAZ var input = $('#input').val().trim();

Comment: So, if you're in a browser, why not use standard browser controls? Or any of the many validation libraries already present? Why do you need to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score -1):

```
<input id="MyNumber" type="number" step="1" onChange="isValidNumber(this.value)" />
<span id="NumberError"></span>

function isValidNumber(num){
    num = parseFloat(num);
  if(Number.isInteger(num)) {
    document.getElementById("NumberError").innerHTML = 'Valid';
    }
  else{
    document.getElementById("NumberError").innerHTML = 'Not Valid';
    }
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

As others can said you can check using isInteger, but if you want for example 10.0 disallowed you can do an extra check as such:

```js
const input = 10.0;

if (Number.isInteger(input) || Math.trunc(input) !== input) {
  console.log('invalid')
}
```